# Use AWS VPN Client over Express VPN

Tags: vpn

I'm travelling overseas for an extended period but need to access a server that requires you to be on the AWS VPN Client, unfortunately, the only VPN still working here (due to government blocks) is express vpn.

Is there a way to use the aws vpn client over the express vpn? I know nothing about VPN's so any help is appreciated (or some other way to make it work I can muddle my way through).

Comment: Is this a Company issue? What do they say?

Comment: That's just how they have it set up unfortunately, if I can't figure out a solution I'm somewhat hosed.

Comment: Can the support be delegated while you are away?

Answer (score 2):

If you can get a router that can use a VPN, it's possible to have
Express VPN on the router and another VPN client on your computer.
This will create the situation of VPN-inside-VPN.

Note that it's possible for the government to scan your messages and detect
this trick, especially if they have an arrangement with Express VPN.
So this might not work where you're going.

Comment: Most android phones allow the hotspot to be used with WiFi and also have an option to "Allow clients to use VPN".

Comment: @mashuptwice: You mean replace the router in my answer with a phone? Yes, this will work just as well, except that the bandwidth might be lower.

Comment: Exactly, this would eliminate the need for additional hardware that could be a burden when traveling.